# Does this concept of "closedness" of a subset of a group have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a group $(G, \cdot)$ and a function $\sigma : G \to \mathbb{Z}$ which is not a homomorphism. I'm curious about $\ker \sigma$, but this is not a subgroup of $G$ so this is finnicky. If it helps, $\ker \sigma$ is closed under inverses and does contain the identity. In place of having closure under products, I'd like to know what is the largest subset $S \subset \ker \sigma$ with $S \cdot S \subset \ker \sigma$, so in a way this is measuring the closedness of $\ker \sigma$. Is there anything written generally around what I'm talking about? Basically any literature studying subsets of groups and what we can say about them would be nice. I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: So may we assume that $\sigma$ has the properties that $\sigma(e)=0$ and $\sigma(x^{-1})=-\sigma(x)$?

Comment: @Randall We have $\sigma(x^{-1}) = \sigma(x)$ and $\sigma(e) = 0$ (actually, there are a few $\sigma$'s I have in mind, only one of which has $\sigma(e) = 0$).

Comment: I would not call the first property "closure under inverses."

Comment: @Randall If $\ker\sigma$ is defined as the fiber $\sigma^{-1}(0)$, the property $\sigma(x^{-1})=\sigma(x)$ implies $\ker\sigma$ is closed under inverses (meaning $x\in\ker\sigma\Rightarrow x^{-1}\in\ker\sigma$).

Comment: Oh, I see now how to think of this as closure.

Comment: I guess that's my real question:  what are we really supposed to assume here?  That $\mathrm{ker}(\sigma)$ is closed under formation of inverses, or that $\sigma$ has some property that *implies* that to be the case.  (I suppose it's possible that it doesn't make a difference.)

Comment: @Randall I didn't augment $\ker \sigma$ to be closed under inverses, so it really is the property $\sigma (x) = \sigma(x^{-1})$ that makes $\ker \sigma$ closed under inverses.

Comment: The property says $\sigma(x)=\sigma(x^{-1})$ says all fibers are closed under inverses. But this has no effect on efforts to investigate maximal subsets $S\subseteq\ker\sigma$ wrt $SS\subseteq\ker\sigma$.

Comment: Why don't you just define what $\sigma$ is instead of these roundabout explanations that only raise more questions? Is $S$ supposed to be closed under taking inverses as well?